# Third cascading Combo Box has problems displaying records

Tags: c#, combobox

I am a beginner programmer developing a C# WinForms solution in VS 2015.

I was successful in cascading two out of three ComboBoxes. The problem is with the third ComboBox, which doesn't display the correct filtered values. It always displays the same values.

Can you please take a look at my code and tell me what's wrong? I really appreciate your time and help. Thank you!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace Bremington
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@;"Data Source=LAPTOP-C30IHOU2;Initial Catalog=BremingtonBackEnd;Integrated Security=True");
        DataRow dr;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            refreshCurso();
        }

        public void refreshCurso()
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from cursos", con);
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);
            con.Close();
            dr = dt.NewRow();
            dt.Rows.InsertAt(dr, 0);
            comboBox1.ValueMember = "cod_curso";
            comboBox1.DisplayMember = "curso";
            comboBox1.DataSource = dt;
        }

        public void refreshModulo(int cod_curso)
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from modulos where cod_curso= @cod_curso", con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("cod_curso", cod_curso);
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);
            con.Close();
            dr = dt.NewRow();
            dt.Rows.InsertAt(dr, 0);
            comboBox2.ValueMember = "cod_modulo";
            comboBox2.DisplayMember = "modulo";
            comboBox2.DataSource = dt;
        }

        public void refreshTurma(int cod_modulo)
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from turmas where cod_modulo= @cod_modulo", con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("cod_modulo", cod_modulo);
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);
            con.Close();
            dr = dt.NewRow();
            dt.Rows.InsertAt(dr, 0);
            comboBox3.ValueMember = "cod_turma";
            comboBox3.DisplayMember = "turma";
            comboBox3.DataSource = dt;
        }

        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex.ToString() != null)
            {
                int cod_curso = Convert.ToInt32(comboBox1.SelectedIndex.ToString());
                refreshModulo(cod_curso);
            }
        }

        private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (comboBox2.SelectedIndex.ToString() != null)
            {
                int cod_modulo = Convert.ToInt32(comboBox2.SelectedIndex.ToString());
                refreshTurma(cod_modulo);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: where is you third `comboBox3_SelectedIndexChanged` event ?

Comment: On an unrelated note, isn't `Convert.ToInt32(comboBox2.SelectedIndex.ToString())` the same as `comboBox2.SelectedIndex)`?

Comment: Same question. Where is the third combo box?

Comment: @Mostafiz and AT-2016 I don't think that's an issue here, since OP wants the third combo box to have filtered values based on the first 2, the selection changed event for this third combobox is therefore not useful for this problem.

Comment: As you are a beginner, I'm going to give you the best advise I can: learn to debug. Put breakpoints to follow the code excution and that way you can see what is going on. In your case, i'd put a breakpoint in  `refreshTurma` method to see if it reach there and what `cod_modulo` are you getting

Comment: ComboBox3 is the last comboBox in the loop, so I thought it didn't need a SelectedIndexChanged event...

Comment: Make sure the first two combos are in fact __hooked up correctly__. Often __two__ similar controls get hooked up to the __same__ event and then only work a little but not really right. To test you may look at the events pane in the properties window.. -